# ExtJS 4: Prevent changing tab using TabBar

Tags: event-handling, tabs, extjs4, tabbar

I don't use tab panel just tab bar, and have to prevent changing tab by some criteria.

In ExtJS docs I found `change` event for `Ext.tab.Bar`, but it fires when tab is already changed. So `preventDefault()` and `return false` are not working in this case.

Second I tried is set `Ext.tab.Tab.handler` property when tabs were initialized, but it fires when tab button is already clicked. So `preventDefault()` and `return false` don't work too.

Can ony body help with this? How can I prevent changing tabs using only `Ext.tab.Tab` and `Ext.tab.Bar`?

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the 'beforetabchange' event on the tab panel itself.

From sencha docs: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-event-beforetabchange . 
 Return false in any listener to cancel the tabchange.

**Edit**

Maybe you could then extend the Ext.tab.Bar component and register the beforechange event by modifying the setActiveTab method, I think it's a pretty easy modification

```
setActiveTab: function(tab) {
        //test the beforechange return
        if (tab.disabled && me.fireEvent('beforechange', tab) === false) {
            return;
        }
        var me = this;
        if (me.activeTab) {
            me.previousTab = me.activeTab;
            me.activeTab.deactivate();
        }
        tab.activate();

        if (me.rendered) {
            me.layout.layout();
            tab.el && tab.el.scrollIntoView(me.layout.getRenderTarget());
        }
        me.activeTab = tab;
        me.fireEvent('change', me, tab, tab.card);
    }
```

Comment: I don't use `Ext.tab.Panel` component, so I'm not able to subscribe to  its events

Comment: Then I'm afraid I have to disappoint you :) -> from sencha docs: TabBar is used internally by a TabPanel and typically should not need to be created manually. ... Anyway have you tried then to return false from beforeactivate event on the tab bar ...

Comment: yep, I saw this message =) And I tryied `beforeactivate` for both: tab and tabbar

Comment: just an idea.. maybe you can add your own event like i edited my respons

Comment: yep, I think to create my own widget based just on tabs and tabbar with its own event for this. thx

Answer (score 0):

Add a controller action "beforeshow" on the tab panel container and disable the listeners. Allows the tabs to behave normally without clickability.

```
component.down("#tabPanel").tabBar.clearListeners();
```